# Android AVD emulator accessing Internet from behind firewall

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to access the Internet from an Android 4.1 AVD emulator, running on a PC behind a firewall?

If I click on the Browser icon, I get an error saying "*Webpage not available.  Make sure you have a data connection.*"
If I click on the Maps icon, I get an error saying "*Network failure.  This application requires a working data connection.*"
If I try to add an Email account, I get an error saying "*Couldn't open connection to server.*"

I have added **-dns-server 10.xxx.xx.31,10.xxx.xx.32  -http-proxy http://10.xxx.xx.201:8080** *(with correct IP addresses!)* to emulator.exe command-line, but this does not seem to make any difference?

I can see the "**3G**" symbol next to a triangle at the top of the screen, and I can toggle it using [**F8**] key, but this does not seem to make any difference either.

Thanks for your help,
Best regards,
James

Comment: try this http://rashidnoorani.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-enable-access-internet-for.html just a blind guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to RESOLVE this problem using the instructions below **:**-

1. Inside ADK emulator, goto Settings icon -> Wireless & Networks ->
   Mobile networks -> Access Point Names
2. Press [F2] and select "New APN"
3. Name = James
4. APN = www
5. Proxy = 10.xxx.xx.201
6. Port = 8080
7. Username = xxxxxxxx
8. Password = xxxxxxxx
9. Press [F2] and select "Save"
10. Click "James" to set as default APN

Now goto Browser and you should be able to see homepage **:**)